# Why is my code for rock papers scissors not executing in JupyterLab?

Tags: python

So recently I tried some python and started with a Rock Paper Scissors code, it worked fine until it didn't, I literally didn't change a thing, it just stopped working in JupyterLab. Also, feel free to share some tips on how to shorten this code if you see any possibilities.

Code:

```
import time

def Rock_Paper_Scissors():

    p1 = input("Type: Rock, Paper, Scissors")
    p2 = input("Type: Rock, Paper, Scissors")
    if p1 == p2:
        print("Game Draw")
    elif p1 == "Rock" and p2 == "Paper":
        print("Player 2 Wins")
    elif p1 == "Rock" and p2 == "Scissors":
        print("Player 1 Wins")
    elif p1 == "Paper" and p2 == "Rock":
        print("Player 1 Wins")
    elif p1 == "Paper" and p2 == "Scissors":
        print("Player 2 Wins")
    elif p1 == "Scissors" and p2 == "Rock":
        print("Player 2 Wins")
    elif p1 == "Scissors" and p2 == "Paper":
        print("Player 1 Wins")
    else:
        print("Check Spelling")

    time.sleep(0.5) #just for fun here
    g = input("Do you want to play another Round?")
    if g == "No":
            print("Thank you for Playing")
    elif g == "Yes":
        Rock_Paper_Scissors()
```

Comment: Did you actually call the function in another cell? You only have the definition here.

Comment: You should also consider adding more description of how it stopped working, runtime error? Unexpected output? Or not running at all?

Comment: No i didnt call the function in another cell, it is only there. @AmarthGûl it just stopped working, and no i dont get any errors or anything just literally nothing when i try to run it it creates a new cell and nothing else happens.

Comment: Well, your code is not doing anything... You just define a function. You need to call with `()` like so `Rock_Paper_Scissors()`

Answer (score 0):

The code runs fine, in JupyterLab and even in my Jupyter Notebook inside VSCode, so I doubt we have enough information to help you with that. Maybe you need to restart your kernel?

However, I'd suggest the following enhancement: Your function includes both the game logic plus input/output management. According to the *'separate concerns'* paradigm you should extract the latter and e.g. put it in another function. Then the logic consists of *'tons of if statements'* (aka. 'beginner code'), resulting in 7 decision points (cyclomatic complexitx = 8). You could easily put the logic into a decision matrix and then you're left with just 2 decision points in the function:

```
def evaluate_game(p1: str, p2: str) -> str:
    """Evalute a Rock-Paper-Sissors game
    :param p1: selection player 1
    :type p1: str
    :param p2: selection player 2
    :type p2: str
    :return: result
    :rtype: str
    """
    DECISION_MATRIX = {
        'Rock': {'Paper': 'Player 2 Wins',
                 'Scissors': 'Player 1 Wins'},
        'Paper': {'Rock': 'Player 1 Wins',
                  'Scissors': 'Player 2 Wins'},
        'Scissors': {'Rock': 'Player 2 Wins',
                     'Paper': 'Player 1 Wins'}}
    if p1 == p2:
        return 'Game Draw'
    else:
        try:
            return DECISION_MATRIX[p1][p2]
        except KeyError:
            return 'Check Spelling'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the function in another cell, as another person mentioned before, and you should be fine :)

```
Rock_Paper_Scissors()
```

You just define the function, you didn't execute it.